# Seletor 'not' não funciona

Tags: html, css, css3

Tenho uma caixa cinza e com uma opacidade baixa e dentro dela uma palavra, ao aplicar o seletor 'not' na 'div' principal para cancelar a opacidade da palavra que está em uma tag "p" cercado por essa 'div' o seletor 'not' não faz sua função e a palavra continua com a opacidade baixa, pretendo fazer com que a palavra não pegue as configurações de opacidade da 'div' principal, sem retirar a tag "p" de dentro dela, ??

```css
body{background-color:#6C9;}
.bl:not(p){ position: relative; 
z-index:-1; 
width:300px; 
opacity:0.5; 
height:200px; 
background-color:#CCC;
border:1px solid #000;
}
p{font-size:25px; 
font-weight:bold; 
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bl">
   <p>BLOCO</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o que acontece é que quando vc coloca opacidade na `div` tudo que está dentro dela também herda essa opacidade e não há como tirar, mesmo como o seletor `:not()` ou usando `!important`.

Usa das técnicas para evitar isso é criando um `pseudo-elemento` nessa `div` que vai ter os elementos dentro, e colocar a opacidade apenas no pseudo-elemento

Veja no exemplo abaixo como fica o seu código com um `::after`

```css
body{
    background-color:#6C9;
}
.bl { 
    position: relative; 
    width:300px; 
    height:200px; 
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.bl::after { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index:-1; 
    width:100%; 
    opacity:0.5; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:#CCC;
}
p {
    font-size:25px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
}
```

```html
<div class="bl">
   <p>BLOCO</p>
</div>
```